Pandas replacing values in array from the gridded (Lat, Lon, Value)
I am stuck to replace (correction) the values of an array from the given Latitude, Longitude and Rain value for hundreds dataset. Here some part of dataset that I am dealing with:
Lat   Lon     Rain
6.125 100.375 197.3
3.870 102.375 163.2
1.625 102.875 215.8
5.375 100.400 188.5
3.125 113.125 272.8
5.375 100.375 204.5

Here are the script that I am stuck with:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Lat':Lat,
    'Lon':Lon,
    'Rain':Rain})
df1 = df1.set_index(['Lat','Lon'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Lat':[3.870, 5.375],
    'Lon':[102.375, 100.375],
    'Rain':[50, 60]})

df2 = df2.set_index(['Lat','Lon'])

output=df1.combine_first(df2).reset_index()

print(output) 

     Lat      Lon   Rain
0  1.625  102.875  215.8
1  3.125  113.125  272.8
2  3.870  102.375  163.2
3  5.375  100.400  188.5
4  5.375  100.375  204.5
5  6.125  100.375  197.3

The output still remain the same, while it suppose to be like this
   Lat      Lon   Rain
0  1.625  102.875  215.8
1  3.125  113.125  272.8
2  3.870  102.375  50.0 --here
3  5.375  100.400  188.5
4  5.375  100.375  60.0 --here
5  6.125  100.375  197.3

and final question how to sort like the default data?
Million thanks in advance.

df1.combine_first(df2) means that you want df1 to have priority in the data - that's the problem, and swapping the order of df1 and df2 will solve it. But in your case, you also need to do a sort, so merge is the better solution, as shown in the answer of @PaulS

@PandaKim, your are right. after swapping df1 and df2, it seems to be ok now. but true I have to make sort...thanks ya

A possible solution, which is based on the following steps:

First, it merges df1 and df2.

After merging, it fills any NaN values in the Rain column of the merged dataframe with the corresponding values from df1['Rain'].


(df1.merge(df2, on=['Lat', 'Lon'], how='left', suffixes=('_x', ''))
 .fillna({'Rain': df1['Rain']}).drop(columns='Rain_x'))


Alternatively, we can use update:
df1 = df1.set_index(['Lat', 'Lon'])
df2 = df2.set_index(['Lat', 'Lon'])

df1.update(df2) # in-place operation
df1.reset_index()


Output:
     Lat      Lon   Rain
0  6.125  100.375  197.3
1  3.870  102.375   50.0
2  1.625  102.875  215.8
3  5.375  100.400  188.5
4  3.125  113.125  272.8
5  5.375  100.375   60.0


yayy...thanks it is working now. seems quite complicated to me. but seriously many thanks to you. now I can proceed to other steps.

Welcome, @Azam! You may want to ask me about what is not so clear in my solution.

@Azam: I have just added a solution based on pandas.update, which should be more clear.

how to use the new suggest of update?? do i have to place it beneath command line (df1.merge(df2, on=['Lat', 'Lon'], how='left', suffixes=('_x', ''))...... or it can be run alternatively??. After I execute the line it come out this error -- KeyError: "None of ['Lat', 'Lon'] are in the columns"

just run the following code: `import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
'Lat': [6.125, 3.870, 1.625, 5.375, 3.125, 5.375],
'Lon': [100.375, 102.375, 102.875, 100.400, 113.125, 100.375],
'Rain': [197.3, 163.2, 215.8, 188.5, 272.8, 204.5]
})
df1 = df1.set_index(['Lat', 'Lon'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
'Lat': [3.870, 5.375],
'Lon': [102.375, 100.375],
'Rain': [50, 60]
})
df2 = df2.set_index(['Lat', 'Lon'])
df1.update(df2)
df1.reset_index()` Please, split the above code by lines, appropriately.

finally its working on my side. thanks a lot.. enjoy your weekend
